# Computer Graphics with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, graphics, pygame, turtle-graphics

I have to make a computer graphics project on "Vote for better Nation" using python in a week..I have a knowledge of pygame but don't know how to create a particular object(like small cartoon man)..And then how to make it move..So please help me if anyone knows how to make a moving object..
Sorry For The English
Thank You

Comment: Have you read the pygame tutorial? It's pretty comprehensive and also covers how to move sprites.

Comment: yeah...I have read it and I can move the images or sprites...But how to make something like a sprite using inbuilt functions or defining new functions and then how to apply rotation or transformations on it that I dont know..

Comment: You are supposed to draw your own sprites using image editing tools. My 1st sprite was made in Paint. To do transformations you can use pygame.transform. You can read more about sprites in http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html

Comment: Okk...Thank You so much..Ill read it and try to do it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, you should read more about http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html and http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html

To create your own sprites, use an image editor like Paint, PS or GIMP.

Answer (score 0):

There is a series of books on Python Graphics called "Python Graphics for Games" (Amazon). It covers vector drawing and animation. Author Mike Ohlson de Fine.